Google Sheets - How to calculate mileage with Google Maps
I've been trying to improve the spreadsheet that I have so that I can save some time.
Here's the deal:

This is the formula:
=IF(M20 = "", , VALUE(GOOGLEMAPS_DISTANCE(M20, N20, "driving")))

And this is the script:
  const GOOGLEMAPS_DISTANCE = (origin, destination, mode) => {
  const { routes: [data] = [] } = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setOrigin(origin)
    .setDestination(destination)
    .setMode(mode)
    .getDirections();

  if (!data) {
    throw new Error('No route found!');
  }

  const { legs: [{ distance: { text: distance } } = {}] = [] } = data;
  return distance.slice(0,-3);
};

This works just fine, it calculates miles from point A to point B and returns the value.
What I want to make work, is empty miles, that is a little bit complicated.
But, I don't know how to get the last value (destination) based on the name in column A and then I would send it to the function to calculate miles.


Try the xlookup() function. Assuming that names are in column A, origins in column M and destinations in column N, put this formula in cell N19:
=let( 
  destination, xlookup(A19, A$2:A18, N$2:N18, M19, 0, -1), 
  if( 
    (M19 = "") + iserror(destination), 
    iferror(ø), 
    value(googlemaps_distance(M19, destination, "driving")) 
  ) 
)

See xlookup(). To avoid exceeding rate limits, try the GoogleMapsDistance custom function.

Excellent idea by @doubleunary.
Although it didn't quite his solution, but gave me an idea how to solve it, and I did.
Solution:
=IF(M25 = "", , VALUE(GOOGLEMAPS_DISTANCE(XLOOKUP(A25,A4:A24,N4:N24,"MISSING",0, -1), M25, "driving")))

Please observe that Stack Exchange sites are not "help forums" nor "discussion boards" but wiki sites that use the Q&A format. See Ask questions, get answers, no distractions and Expected Behavior. This answer looks like a subset of the other one.
